# System.InvalidCastException 'specified cast is not valid.'

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, mvvm

In the ViewModel this event handler:

```
private void Model_MineAdded(object sender, MineEventArgs e)
{
    if (_model.Mines.Count > Mines.Count)
    {
        Mines.Add(new Shape
        {
            X      = _model.Mines[e.MineID].X,
            Y      = _model.Mines[e.MineID].Y,
            Width  = _model.Mines[e.MineID].Width,
            Height = _model.Mines[e.MineID].Height,
            Weight = _model.Mines[e.MineID].Weight
        });  // this line throws the exception
    }
}
```

throws this exception:

> System.InvalidCastException 'specified cast is not valid.'

---

**MORE DETAILS**

I have a(nother) problem with a **game application** I have to write using **Xamarin.Forms** (and **MVVM**).
I already asked a question about this game ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jftif.png): [Binding property in Xamarin.Forms using MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70526383/binding-property-in-xamarin-forms-using-mvvm)).
The application is a simple 2D game where the user controls a submarine and there are mines falling down, so the user has to avoid these mines.
The submarine can move in four ways (up, down, left, right).

I already made this game using WPF (and WinForms). It was a lot easier with WPF, I used a `Canvas` for the game area, an `ItemsControl` for the mines (because these are generated in runtime using a timer), but in Xamarin I just don't really know what's going on. I use a `RelativeLayout` for the game area, and first a `CollectionView` for the mines, but the mines didn't do nothing (at least they were displayed). Now I'm using a `ListView` for the mines, but received this exception:

> System.InvalidCastException 'specified cast is not valid.'

This screenshot of the WPF version may help to understand what I'm trying to describe:
[image: WPF version of the game]

So the question is how can I display the game area and the mines so that the game works properly in Xamarin.Forms using MVVM architecture?

These are the relevant code snippets:

GamePage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SubmarineGame.View.GamePage"
             Title="Submarine Game">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <RelativeLayout Grid.Row="0" 
                            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{Binding GameAreaWidth}" 
                            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{Binding GameAreaHeight}">
                <Image RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
                    Type=RelativeToParent, 
                    Property=Width, 
                    Factor=1}" 
                       RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
                    Type=RelativeToParent, 
                    Property=Height, 
                    Factor=1}" 
                       Aspect="AspectFill" 
                       Source="sea.png" />
                <Image RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Constant=50}" 
                       RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Constant=50}" 
                       RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
                    Type=RelativeToParent, 
                    Property=Width, 
                    Factor=0.9}" 
                       RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
                    Type=RelativeToParent, 
                    Property=Height, 
                    Factor=0.1}" 
                       Source="pausebutton.png">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ExitCommand}" />
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
                <Image RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Constant=64}" 
                       RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Constant=64}" 
                       RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
                    Type=RelativeToParent, 
                    Property=Width, 
                    Factor=0.8}" 
                       RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
                    Type=RelativeToParent, 
                    Property=Width, 
                    Factor=0.9}" 
                       Source="downarrow.png">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding StepCommand}" CommandParameter="Down" />
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
                <Image RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Constant=64}" 
                       RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Constant=64}" 
                       RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
                    Type=RelativeToParent, 
                    Property=Width, 
                    Factor=0.8}" 
                       RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
                    Type=RelativeToParent, 
                    Property=Width, 
                    Factor=0.7}" 
                       Source="uparrow.png">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding StepCommand}" CommandParameter="Up" />
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
                <Image RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Constant=64}" 
                       RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Constant=64}" 
                       RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
                    Type=RelativeToParent, 
                    Property=Width, 
                    Factor=0.7}" 
                       RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
                    Type=RelativeToParent, 
                    Property=Width, 
                    Factor=0.8}" 
                       Source="leftarrow.png">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding StepCommand}" CommandParameter="Left" />
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
                <Image RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Constant=64}" 
                       RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Constant=64}" 
                       RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
                    Type=RelativeToParent, 
                    Property=Width, 
                    Factor=0.9}" 
                       RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
                    Type=RelativeToParent, 
                    Property=Width, 
                    Factor=0.8}" 
                       Source="rightarrow.png">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding StepCommand}" CommandParameter="Right" />
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
                <!--<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Mines}" 
                                    ItemsLayout="HorizontalList" 
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                                    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
                                 Type=RelativeToParent, 
                                 Property=Width, 
                                 Factor=1}" 
                                    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
                                 Type=RelativeToParent, 
                                 Property=Height, 
                                 Factor=1}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Constant=64}" 
                                   RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Constant=64}" 
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{Binding XC}" 
                                   RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{Binding YC}" 
                                   Source="nuclearbomb.png" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>-->

                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Mines}" 
                          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                          BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Constant=64}" 
                                   RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Constant=64}" 
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{Binding XC}" 
                                   RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{Binding YC}" 
                                   Source="nuclearbomb.png"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>

                <Image RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Constant=64}" 
                       RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Constant=64}" 
                       RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{Binding Submarine.XC}" 
                       RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{Binding Submarine.YC}" 
                       Source="submarine.png" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Start" Grid.Row="1">
                <Label Text="Game time: " />
                <Label Text="{Binding GameTime}" />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="End" Grid.Row="1">
                <Label Text="Destroyed mines: " />
                <Label Text="{Binding DestroyedMineCount}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The `Shape` class in the ViewModel (the `XC` and `YC` properties were needed because of a conversion error (`RelativeLayout`)):

```
public class Shape : ViewModelBase
{
    private Int32 _x;
    private Int32 _y;

    public Int32 X 
    { 
        get { return _x; }
        set
        {
            if (_x != value)
            {
                _x = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(XC));
            }
        }
    }
    public Int32 Y
    {
        get { return _y; }
        set
        {
            if (_y != value)
            {
                _y = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(YC));
            }
        }
    }
    public Int32 Width  { get; set; }
    public Int32 Height { get; set; }
    public Int32 Weight { get; set; }
        
    public Constraint XC { get { return Constraint.Constant(X); } }
    public Constraint YC { get { return Constraint.Constant(Y); } }
}
```

The `Mines` and the `Submarine` in the ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Shape> Mines { get; set; }
public Submarine Submarine               { get; set; }
```

The `Shape` class in the Model (Persistence):

```
public enum ShapeType { Submarine, Mine }
public class Shape
{
    public ShapeType Type { get; set; }
    public Int32 X        { get; set; }
    public Int32 Y        { get; set; }
    public Int32 Width    { get; private set; }
    public Int32 Height   { get; private set; }
    public Int32 Weight   { get; set; }

    public Shape(ShapeType type, Int32 startX, Int32 startY, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 weight)
    {
        Type = type;
        X = startX;
        Y = startY;
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        Weight = weight;
    }
}
```

I think these are the most relevant parts of the project, I hope I don't miss something.
Thanks for your time and sorry for my English!

Comment: Have you looked into SkiaSharp?  It provides a drawing canvas.  I'm not sure a ListView or CollectionView is a good choice for a game.  And it would be really helpful if you includes a screenshot or mockup of what you want the UI to look like.

Comment: That said, the question you actually asked "how can I display the game area and the mines so that the game works properly" is far too broad to be answered, especially has we have no idea what "game area" is, or what "game works properly" means.

Comment: Finally, the exception you are getting - we have no idea what line causes it so it's impossible to determine what the problem is.  You need to look at the stack trace or catch the exception in the debugger to determine which line is the source.  Knowing that will allow us to help you fix it.  Please read [ask] before posting for guidance on writing an on-topic question.

Comment: Thanks @Jason for your remarks! I edited the question so I hope it will be fine now!
Yes, I tried SkiaSharp, but I think not as deep as I should, so also thanks for this advice!

Comment: I think just using an AbsoluteLayout would probably be a much better idea.  But you still haven't explained where the `InvalidCastException` is coming from.  And your question is still incredibly broad.

Comment: I'm aware that my answer will not help with your problem, consider it more as a bit of advice. Xamarin.Forms it's a framework for professional applications, most of the controls won't help you to create a videogame, consider using another framework like [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) with [Flame Engine](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame) or an ACTUAL videogame framework like [Unity](https://unity.com/es) or [Godot](https://godotengine.org/), personally, I highly recommend you godot for your project.

Comment: @Jason I wrote a comment to the line where the `InvalidCastException` is coming from and I indicated above this that it's in the ViewModel. Sorry if I don't understand. Do you mean that I should give a more precise explanation?
Yes, I tried the `AbsoluteLayout` but there were conversion problems like with the `RelativeLayout` (that's why I use `XC` and `YC` properties). Is there a way to handle this conversion problem when I use `AbsoluteLayout`?

Comment: It won't be any easier with `AbsoluteLayout`. Stick with `RelativeLayout` - and consider using a constraint that scales with the size of game area (see second part of my answer). After you solve the current problem (see first part of my answer), create a new question for any future problem you have. Include a link back to this question, so you don't need to duplicate a lot of code - in each question, show just the code involved in that specific issue. (When in doubt, its fine to show more code than needed, so it was good to have it all in this question, just in case it mattered.)

Comment: I forgot to mention - don't use `ListView`. That isn't designed for this. Change that to a second `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Take the 8 lines of the statement that gave the exception. Find out exactly what causes it.

```
Mines.Add(new Shape
    {
        X      = _model.Mines[e.MineID].X,
        Y      = _model.Mines[e.MineID].Y,
        Width  = _model.Mines[e.MineID].Width,
        Height = _model.Mines[e.MineID].Height,
        Weight = _model.Mines[e.MineID].Weight
    });  // this line throws the exception
```

Do this one step at a time - now where is the exception?

```
var shape = new Shape();
var mine = _model.Mines[e.MineID];
shape.X = mine.X;
shape.Y = ...;
...
Mines.Add(shape);
```

---

A complete tested version, to compare to yours.

Note that instead of a `ListView`, I used a `RelativeLayout` to hold the mines (here, Sprites). In yours, this would be a RelativeLayout inside of your current RelativeLayout. I don't recommend ListView for this.

NOTE: If you want to make coordinates scale automatically with the game area, see `X` and `XConstraint`.

As you discovered, currently it is necessary to create `XConstraint` and `YConstraint` properties for X and Y of each sprite.

I put `Sprites` directly on the page's code behind. If you have a separate VM, move them there.

SpritesPage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XFSOAnswers.SpritesPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, *" BackgroundColor="Pink" >
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="The Game" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" />
            <RelativeLayout x:Name="GameArea" Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="Fill"
                            BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Sprites}"
                            BackgroundColor="LightBlue" Margin="8,0,8,8">
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!--RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor={Binding X}}"
                            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor={Binding Y}}"-->
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                               RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{Binding XConstraint}"
                               RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{Binding YConstraint}"
                               />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

SpritesPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace XFSOAnswers
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class SpritesPage : ContentPage
    {
        public SpritesPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Model3> Sprites { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Model3> {
            new Model3(),
            new Model3("b", 0.4, 0),
            new Model3("c", 0, 0.2),
        };

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            AnimationLoop();
        }

        private void AnimationLoop()
        {
            // Animation test.
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                // HACK to make sure page is displayed before begin animation loop.
                await Task.Delay(500);

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(100);
                    Sprites[0].X += 0.01;
                    Sprites[0].Y += 0.01;

                    // Might need this on some platforms.
                    //this.GameArea.ForceLayout();

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Model3.cs:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XFSOAnswers
{
    public class Model3 : BindableObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // (x, Y) = (0.0, 0.0) at top-left, (1.0, 1.0) at bottom-right.
        // Currently, it doesn't seem to be possible to bind these directly.
        // RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor={Binding X}}"
        // gave error "No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Factor", or mismatching type between value and property."
        public double X
        {
            get => _x;
            set
            {
                _x = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(XConstraint));
            }
        }
        private double _x;
        public Constraint XConstraint => Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return parent.Width * X; });

        public double Y
        {
            get => _y;
            set
            {
                _y = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(YConstraint));
            }
        }
        private double _y;
        public Constraint YConstraint => Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return parent.Height * Y; });


        public Model3(string name = "a", double x = 0, double y = 0)
        {
            Name = name;
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }
}
```